# How to move git repository to a folder and merge another repository into original?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repository for an **httpdocs** folder. I had someone write some code for a module that lives a few subdirectories into **httpdocs**. This was stored in a separate repository. He also wrote some code that lives above httpdocs. I would like to merge everything into one repository.

Repo 1: (httpdocs)

```
/
```

Repo 2: (root)

```
/src
/vendor
/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/custom_module
```

How do I move **Repo 1** up a level and put everything in a folder called httpdocs and then merge with **Repo 2** all while keeping the history?

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [subtree strategy option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-subtreeltpathgt) of the `git merge` command is for.

Repo 2, the root one, should be where you do the merging. You add repo 1 as a remote and do a merge along the lines of `git merge -Xsubtree=/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/custom_module httpdocs/master`.

Don't fear a bit of experimenting; if you get it wrong the first time around, just reset to the starting point and do it over. Until you push the result back the the central repo, it does not matter.

Note that if you later do some updates in Repo 1, git should be able to figure the path on re-merges itself, so then `git merge -ssubtree httpdocs/master` should work. But first time around you must tell it where to put the submodule.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.